# Syntax error when calling variable in bash

Tags: bash, rsync

Here is my code:

```
#!bin/bash

id=$(sshpass -p password ssh -tt username@ipaddress -p PORT "grep --include=\*.cr -rlw '/usr/local/bin/' -e '$1' | cut -c16-")
echo $id
sshpass -p password rsync -avHPe 'ssh -p PORT' username@ipaddress:/usr/local/bin/"$id" /usr/local/bin/
```

id echos correctly, but I get an rsync error when trying to call the variable.

If I manually populate and run rsync, the command works, so I'm not sure what is going on.

Rsync gives me the following output on error.

```
rsync: link_stat "/usr/local/bin/match.cr\#015" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

It seems to be grabbing extra characters?  Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Try typing the shell command on its own to see if it returns the unexpected characters.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your file contains Windows specific "CR LF" characters. You need to convert these to Linux specific "LF" characters in your script. You can use a tool like dos2unix or Notepad++.

Comment: I thought that might be what that is, is there an easy way to do it via SSH?, like convert the file remotely?

Comment: I manually did dos2unix on the remote file, and it's still coming back with same garble, do I need to run some form of SED to cut off the output?  Echoing the variable will display it correctly

Comment: Have you tried `tr -d '\r'` on the file? Could you also try it on a dummy folder where you don't have those windows files?

Comment: so adding that and echoing id, I still get the correct output, but calling it in the next will cause it to fail =(

Weird issue. I thought I might have to double quote or bracket something, but not used this form of command yet.